# Print SQL Query in Java (JTextPane)

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, prepared-statement

I made a simple game that is also connected to a database, everything works fine, but where I'm having issues is having the program print a query I made to show the entries in the DB (scores)

```
String sql = "select * from scores";
        
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps =
                conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                JTP.setText(""+ps.toString());
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I run the game (the ScoreBoard is made to show up with the press of a button) and when I open the ScoreBoard, the text I get is this:

> "org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4PreparedStatement@691f5716"

I'm relatively new with all things Java, so I have no idea what this one means... any ideas?

(edit: JTP is JTextPane)

Comment: Are you trying to print the SQL query itself, or the results it queried from the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the question is not clear enough. I think what you're trying to do is to get the result of a query from the DB.
This is one approach:
**This method will execute our query**

```
 public ResultSet selectEntity(String query) {
        ResultSet result;
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            result = statement.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            //handle your exception here
            return null;
        }
        return result;
 }
```

**This method will get the result of the query and pass to our JTextPane**

```
private void printScore()
{
    //we're calling the method that executes the query
    ResultSet resultSet = this.selectEntity("SELECT * FROM scores");
    try {
        // I assume that the score is saved as Integer in the DB, so I'll use **getInt()**
        while(resultSet.next()) textPane.setText(""+resultSet.getInt(1));           
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //handle your exception here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are fine.
I think the problem is you prepare the statement but never you run the query and get the results.

```
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ...you run the query.. an then use the results
    ...
    JTP.setText(""+results.toString());


    try
    {
      // create our mysql database connection
      String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
      String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
      Class.forName(myDriver);
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");
      
      String query = "SELECT * FROM SCORES";

      // create the java statement
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();
      
      // execute the query, and get a java resultset
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
      
      // iterate through the java resultset
      while (rs.next())
      {
        int id = rs.getInt("id");
        String score1 = rs.getString("score1");
        String score2 = rs.getString("score2");
        
        // print the results
        System.out.format("%s, %s, %s\n", id, score1, score2);
      }
      st.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

For your help, read more about Java and his objects for interact with databases.